# Image URL not retrieved

Tags: android

Am making an app that registers user for gcm services by retrieving user data from google plus. The app is able to retrieve the data and register in the server.Once registered the users information is stored in an intent and passed to the next activity.However the app crushes on starting the next activity as it fails to retrieve image url to be passed to picasso. Kindly help

LOG CAT

```
10-11 02:33:50.427  16208-16208/com.smartdevelopers.kandie.nicedrawer E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.smartdevelopers.kandie.nicedrawer, PID: 16208
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient.setWriteTimeout
            at com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader.defaultOkHttpClient(OkHttpDownloader.java:34)
            at com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader.<init>(OkHttpDownloader.java:76)
            at com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader.<init>(OkHttpDownloader.java:55)
            at com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader.<init>(OkHttpDownloader.java:45)
            at com.squareup.picasso.Utils$OkHttpLoaderCreator.create(Utils.java:424)
            at com.squareup.picasso.Utils.createDefaultDownloader(Utils.java:250)
            at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso$Builder.build(Picasso.java:832)
            at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.with(Picasso.java:662)
            at com.smartdevelopers.kandie.nicedrawer.NavigationDrawerFragment.setUserData(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:257)
            at com.smartdevelopers.kandie.nicedrawer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:66)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
            at 
            4)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

ActivityGplus.java

```
package com.smartdevelopers.kandie.nicedrawer;

/**
 * Created by 4331 on 14/07/2015.
 */
public class ActivityGplus extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
    // Logcat tag
    private static final String TAG = "ActivityGplus";

    // Profile pic image size in pixels
    private static final int PROFILE_PIC_SIZE = 400;

    // Google client to interact with Google API
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private boolean mIntentInProgress;

    private boolean mSignInClicked;

    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

    private SignInButton btnSignIn;
    private Button btnEnter;

    String personPhotoUrl;
    String personName;
    String email;

    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    AtomicInteger msgId = new AtomicInteger();
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    Context context;
    String regid;
    String msg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gplus_activity);
        //Cloud Messaging
        if(isUserRegistered(context)){
            startActivity(new Intent(ActivityGplus.this,MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }else {
            // Initializing google plus api client
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API)
                    .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
                /*
        Adding KenBurns View
        */
            KenBurnsView kbv = (KenBurnsView) findViewById(R.id.imageBurn);
            kbv.setTransitionListener(new KenBurnsView.TransitionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTransitionStart(Transition transition) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {

                }
            });
            btnSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
            btnEnter=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_main);
            context = getApplicationContext();

            // Button click listeners
            btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
            // Check device for Play Services APK. If check succeeds, proceed with
            //  GCM registration.

            if (checkPlayServices()) {
                gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
                regid = getRegistrationId(context);

                if (regid.isEmpty()) {
                    registerInBackground();
                }


            } else {
                Log.i("pavan", "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
            }
        }

    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }


    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_sign_in:
                // Signin button clicked
                signInWithGplus();
                break;
            case R.id.btn_main:
                //enter to the main activity
                enterMain();
                break;

        }
    }


    private void enterMain() {
        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.smartdevelopers.kandie.nicedrawer.MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void revokeGplusAccess() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient)
                    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(Status arg0) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "User access revoked!");
                            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                            updateUI(false);
                        }

                    });
        }

    }

    private void signOutFromGplus() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            updateUI(false);
        }
    }

    private void signInWithGplus() {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mSignInClicked = true;
            resolveSignInError();
        }

    }

    private void resolveSignInError() {
        if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (!connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(connectionResult.getErrorCode(), this,
                    0).show();
            return;
        }

        if (!mIntentInProgress) {
            // Store the ConnectionResult for later usage
            mConnectionResult = connectionResult;

            if (mSignInClicked) {
                // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to
                // resolve all
                // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
                resolveSignInError();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                mSignInClicked = false;
            }

            mIntentInProgress = false;

            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mSignInClicked = false;
        // Get user's information
        getProfileInformation();

        // Update the UI after signin
        updateUI(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        updateUI(false);

    }

    /**
     * Updating the UI, showing/hiding buttons and profile layout
     * */
    private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
            btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnEnter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {
            btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnEnter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Fetching user's information name, email, profile pic
     * */
    private void getProfileInformation() {
        try {
            if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
                Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                        .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
                personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
                personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
                String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
                email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

                Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", plusProfile: "
                        + personGooglePlusProfile + ", email: " + email
                        + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);

                personPhotoUrl = personPhotoUrl.substring(0,
                        personPhotoUrl.length() - 2)
                        + PROFILE_PIC_SIZE;

                sendRegistrationIdToBackend();
                //putting extra information in the Intent
//                Intent intent=new Intent(ActivityGplus.this,MainActivity.class);
//                intent.putExtra("username",personName);
//                intent.putExtra("mail",email);
//                intent.putExtra("picture", personPhotoUrl);
//                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Google Cloud Messaging
     */
    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        Util.PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        String registrationId = prefs.getString(Util.PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
        if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
            return "";
        }
        // Check if app was updated; if so, it must clear the registration ID
        // since the existing registration ID is not guaranteed to work with
        // the new app version.
        int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(Util.PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
            Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
            return "";
        }
        return registrationId;
    }


    private boolean isUserRegistered(Context context) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        String User_name = prefs.getString(Util.USER_NAME, "");
        if (User_name.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
    private void registerInBackground() {
        new AsyncTask() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Object[] params) {
                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(ActivityGplus.this);
                    }
                    regid = gcm.register(Util.SENDER_ID);
                    msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;
                    // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP,
                    //GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;/ so it can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
                    // The request to your server should be authenticated if your app
                    // is using accounts.
                    // sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

                    // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the device
                    // will send upstream messages to a server that echo back the
                    // message using the 'from' address in the message.

                    // Persist the registration ID - no need to register again.
                    storeRegistrationId(context, regid);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                    // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                    // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                    // exponential back-off.
                }
                return msg;
            }
        }.execute();

    }

    private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            return packageInfo.versionCode;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            // should never happen
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
        }
    }

    private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(Util.PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);
        editor.putInt(Util.PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
        editor.commit();
    }

    private void storeUserDetails(Context context) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(Util.EMAIL,email);
        editor.putString(Util.USER_NAME, personName);
        editor.commit();
    }
    private SharedPreferences getGCMPreferences(Context context) {
        // This sample app persists the registration ID in shared preferences, but
        // how you store the registration ID in your app is up to you.
        return getSharedPreferences(ActivityGplus.class.getSimpleName(),
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
    //  private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() {
        // Your implementation here.
        new SendGcmToServer().execute();
// Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
        // AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest, "jsonRequest");
    }

    private class SendGcmToServer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String url = Util.register_url+"?name="+personName+"&email="+email+"&regId="+regid;
            Log.i("pavan", "url" + url);

            OkHttpClient client_for_getMyFriends = new OkHttpClient();

            String response = null;
            // String response=Utility.callhttpRequest(url);

            try {
                url = url.replace(" ", "%20");
                response = callOkHttpRequest(new URL(url),
                        client_for_getMyFriends);
                for (String subString : response.split("<script", 2)) {
                    response = subString;
                    break;
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //Toast.makeText(context,"response "+result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if (result != null) {
                if (result.equals("success")) {
                    storeUserDetails(context);
                    Intent intent=new Intent(ActivityGplus.this,MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("username",personName);
                    intent.putExtra("mail", email);
                    intent.putExtra("picture", personPhotoUrl);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Try Again" + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(context, "Check net connection ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
    // Http request using OkHttpClient
    String callOkHttpRequest(URL url, OkHttpClient tempClient)
            throws IOException {

        HttpURLConnection connection = tempClient.open(url);

        connection.setConnectTimeout(40000);
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            // Read the response.
            in = connection.getInputStream();
            byte[] response = readFully(in);
            return new String(response, "UTF-8");
        } finally {
            if (in != null)
                in.close();
        }
    }

    byte[] readFully(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        for (int count; (count = in.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        return out.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
            implements NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
        private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
        private Toolbar mToolbar;
        Intent intent;
        String user_name;
        String user_email;
        String user_photo_url;
        Fragment fragment;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
            setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
            PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this,R.xml.settings,false);
            intent=getIntent();
            user_name=intent.getStringExtra("username");
            user_email=intent.getStringExtra("mail");
            user_photo_url=intent.getStringExtra("picture");
            mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
          getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_drawer);
            mNavigationDrawerFragment.setup(R.id.fragment_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer), mToolbar);
                mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUserData(user_name, user_email, user_photo_url);
    //        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUserData("John Doe", "johndoe@doe.com", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.avatar));
        }
        @Override
        public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            Fragment fragment;
            String title=getString(R.string.app_name);
            switch (position) {
                case 0: //News Fragment//todo
                    fragment=new NewsFragment();                 fragment=getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(NewsFragment.TAG);
                    if (fragment==null){
                        fragment=new NewsFragment();
                    }getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,fragment,NewsFragment.TAG).commit();
                    break;
                case 1: //Politics Fragment//todo
                    fragment=new PoliticsFragment();
                    fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(PoliticsFragment.TAG);
                    if (fragment == null) {
                        fragment = new PoliticsFragment();
                    }         getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment, PoliticsFragment.TAG).commit();
                    break;
                case 2: //Sports Fragment//todo
                    fragment=new SportsFragment();               fragment=getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(SportsFragment.TAG);
                    if(fragment==null){
                        fragment=new SportsFragment();
                    }                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,fragment,SportsFragment.TAG).commit();
                    break;
                case 3: //Music Fragment//todo
                    fragment=new MusicFragment();               fragment=getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MusicFragment.TAG);
                    if(fragment==null){
                        fragment=new MusicFragment();
                    }               getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,fragment,MusicFragment.TAG).commit();
    //                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.smartdevelopers.kandie.nicedrawer.TabsActivity.class);
    //                startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 4: //Art and Culture  Fragment//todo
                    fragment=new ArtandCultureFragment();                  fragment=getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(ArtandCultureFragment.TAG);
                    if(fragment==null){
                        fragment=new ArtandCultureFragment();
                    }             getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,fragment,ArtandCultureFragment.TAG).commit();
                    break;
                case 5: //Agriculture Fragment//todo
                    fragment=new AgricultureFragment();
fragment=getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(AgricultureFragment.TAG);
                    if(fragment==null){
                        fragment=new AgricultureFragment();
                    }
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,fragment,AgricultureFragment.TAG).commit();
                    break;
                case 6: //Counties Fragment//todo
                    fragment=new CountiesFragment();       fragment=getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CountiesFragment.TAG);
                    if(fragment==null){
                        fragment=new CountiesFragment();
                    }
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,fragment,CountiesFragment.TAG).commit();
                    break;
                case 7: //Counties Fragment//todo
                    fragment=new NotificationFragment();
                    fragment=getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(NotificationFragment.TAG);
                    if(fragment==null){
                        fragment=new NotificationFragment();
                    }                 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,fragment,NotificationFragment.TAG).commit();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if (mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen())
                mNavigationDrawerFragment.closeDrawer();
            else
                super.onBackPressed();
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return true;
            }
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            switch (id){
                case R.id.menu_favorites:Bundle data_Bundle=new Bundle();
                    data_Bundle.putInt("id", 0);
                    //Refresh content
                    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.smartdevelopers.kandie.nicedrawer.ReadArticleActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtras(data_Bundle);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case R.id.action_settings:Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                    bundle.putInt("id", 1);
                    Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.smartdevelopers.kandie.nicedrawer.SettingsFragment.class);
                    i.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            if(fragment!=null)    this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,fragment).commit();
            else
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you encountered the bug [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/497).

It is `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`.